# Positioning Images in a Column

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position an image in the bottom right corner, below some text in the left column of my index.html page, but I can't quite get it where I want. I've wrapped the image in a div tag and set the position to absolute in my CSS file and that centers the image below the text, just not to the right though.

**HTML**

```
<main>
  <div class="column left">
    <h3>
     About us:
    </h3>
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        The purpose of Beginning Band Players is to provide students and parents
        with the necessary resources for a successful start in any band program.
      </p>
      <div class="staff">
      <img src="staff2-e.png" alt="staff" height="225" width="400">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <h4>
      What to Expect:
    </h4>
    <p>
      Students can learn a little about each instrument found in beginning band
      programs and decide which one they like best. They'll be able to see and
      hear what each instrument sounds like.
    </p>
    <h3>
      Additional Resources
    </h3>
    <p>
      Students may also need additional equipment such as practice books or supplies
      to help maintain their instruments. Links to such supplies can be found on the
      Additional Equipment page.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

**CSS**

```
.column  {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 75%;
}
.right {
  width: 25%;
}
.text {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.staff {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding `text-align: right;` to `staff` class.

```css
.column  {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 75%;
}
.right {
  width: 25%;
}
.text {
  font-size: 25px;
}
.staff {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="column left">
    <h3>
     About us:
    </h3>
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        The purpose of Beginning Band Players is to provide students and parents
        with the necessary resources for a successful start in any band program.
      </p>
      <div class="staff">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg" alt="staff" height="225" width="400">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <h4>
      What to Expect:
    </h4>
    <p>
      Students can learn a little about each instrument found in beginning band
      programs and decide which one they like best. They'll be able to see and
      hear what each instrument sounds like.
    </p>
    <h3>
      Additional Resources
    </h3>
    <p>
      Students may also need additional equipment such as practice books or supplies
      to help maintain their instruments. Links to such supplies can be found on the
      Additional Equipment page.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This did what I wanted it to. I also did `float: right;` and that also seemed to work

Comment: Using `float` is usually not the right choice. Use `flexbox` to solve the problem. If you add some other contents in `main` or out of `main` you can find main has **some issue**.

Comment: Do you know [what should asker do when someone answers to his/her question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?